# Calculate difference between rows in repeated measurement database R

Tags: r

I have a data-frame like this:

```
ID  Time  Testscore
20  2     300
20  1     350
20  3     -150
30  2     200
30  1     100
40  1     300
40  2     NA
```

Three questions:

1. How can I calculate the difference between last score and first score grouped by ID and Time whereas the last time is the bigger number (some with more repeated measures than other)
2. How to deal with NA in calculation
3. Is there a way to arrange the Time varible in ascending ordered and keep the ID grouped up?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are responsible for telling us what rules should apply to groups with only one member and NA's.

Comment: Groups with one measurement the last score is the first one. 
The groups with NA as the last score the difference is NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tapply`

```
with(dat, tapply(Testscore, ID, \(x) x[length(x)] - x[1]))
#   20   30   40 
# -450 -100   NA
```

or `ave`.

```
transform(dat, d=ave(Testscore, ID, FUN=\(x) x[length(x)] - x[1]))
#   ID Time Testscore    d
# 1 20    2       300 -450
# 2 20    1       350 -450
# 3 20    3      -150 -450
# 4 30    2       200 -100
# 5 30    1       100 -100
# 6 40    1       300   NA
# 7 40    2        NA   NA
```

Here by **ID and Time**, but doesn't make much sense with your sample data.

```
with(dat, tapply(Testscore, list(ID, Time), \(x) x[length(x)] - x[1]))
transform(dat, d=ave(Testscore, ID, Time, FUN=\(x) x[length(x)] - x[1]))
```

Comment: I don't think you are getting the correct answers without applying the sort operation first. For instance the first groups difference of Time==1 and Time==3 is -500

Comment: @IRTFM I admit it's ambiguous, OP wanted "the difference between last score and first score" which is what my solution aims to provide. You're right that it doesn't look at the Time, where I felt that wasn't asked.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting dataframe rows is usually done with the `order` function.

```
 dfrm <- dfrm[ order(dfrm$ID, dfrm$Time) , ]
```

Then you can use `split` in traditional R or `group_by` in the tidyverse to separately handle the difference calculations.

```
 diffs <- sapply( split(dfrm, dfrm$ID), function(grp){
             grp[ max(grp$Time, na.rm=TRUE), "Testscore"] -
              grp[ min(grp$Time, na.rm=TRUE), "Testscore"] }

diffs
#---------------
  20   30   40 
-500  100   NA
```

I didn't see a request to put these differences along side the dataframe.

Comment: Hey there thanks for the help 
I wrote the same code, however it didn't work, I received this message:
Error in '$' <-.data. Frame '('*tmp, diff, value c = ('22'= 0, '142 = 0.199,: 
replacement has 1205 rows, data has 3041.

Comment: I don’t think it could have been the same code. I didn’t use the $<- function.

Comment: Ok I fixed it and it worked wonderfully!
How do I add the diffs variable to the the existing data frame?
I saw this command:
merge (df, diffs, by = "ID")
It isn't working for me, how can I fix it?

Comment: merge(df, as.list(dfrm), by=ID)

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
    arrange(ID, Time) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Diff = last(Testscore) - first(Testscore))
# A tibble: 7 × 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
#      ID  Time Testscore  Diff
#   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    20     1       350  -500
# 2    20     2       300  -500
# 3    20     3      -150  -500
# 4    30     1       100   100
# 5    30     2       200   100
# 6    40     1       300    NA
# 7    40     2        NA    NA
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the help
I wrote the exact same code, when I run the command for some reason the new variable (Diff) doesn't appear in the database, and when I run summary(Diff)
I get all NA. 
What can I do? 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you assign it to a variable? After the last line just add `-> df` to the end to actually change `df`.